# How to inherit attributes in class/block diagram using Eclipse Papyrus?

Tags: eclipse, uml, modeling, papyrus, sysml

I'm creating a  very simple class diagram using the Eclipse Papyrus but I'm not able to represent instances correctly.

First of all, I'm using the [SysML 1.6 profile](https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/components/sysml16/releases/2.2.0/p2/), so my classes are actually represented in a Block Diagram instead of classes, but I believe that this does not change anything in my problem.

After creating a simple class/block in my block definition diagram (bdd) I defined some attributes for my block like the example below:

[image: class/block diagram created using Papyrus with some attributes and operations]

When I tried to create some instances of my block ("parts" in SysML naming convention) using an "Instance Specification" I'm not able to inherit these attributes and fill them with actual information like the "name" and "quantity" in this example.

[image: Instance/part diagram without attributtes]

It's possible to see that my classifier is correctly set as "My component".

The [Papyrus documentation for the Object diagram](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Papyrus_Starter_Guide#6.3.2.9_Create_new_objects) is clear and says that these Instance Specification should include my attributes so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried since now:

- Create instances in the same block diagram (bdd);
- Create instances in another dedicated diagram of the type internal block definition (ibd);
- Use the Papyrus context menu to show/hide all my compartments. Any of them works to show my attributes.

Apparently, the same problem occurs without any SysML profile and using pure UML like this question [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/489259/) (from 2016!!)

Papyrus version: 6.1.0

Comment: I would guess that you're chasing after a bug...